# Magento Migration and Login Page Cookie Errors

Tags: error, login, migration

I recently migrated from a VPS to a dedicated server, and the migration, while a little bumpy, went smoother than I ever imagined. However, there has been one lingering issue. The dreaded customer login, page refreshes, customer still not logged in.

Now I have read dozens and dozens of related errors, all seemingly a list to troubleshoot through with file edits and the like. I feel like this is not at all necessary in my particular situation (I could be wrong).

The way to escape this login refresh bug, on our end, is to simply delete your cookies. Magento will reissue new cookies correctly and you are able to carry on and login like normal. Seemingly, before the migration, my cookies were set to last a very long time, and it is my fear that customers in the future will be unable to login without refreshing and deleting their cookies.

Is there any way to determine how long these cookies could last and are there any solutions to getting rid of this erroneous cookies on the customer's local machine?

Comment: Ah, interesting. The previous sessions were presumedly not migrated, so the new server has no session data to match the cookie being sent with the request. I'd expect Magento to just set a new cookie. If the user tries to log in twice, does that resolve it?

Comment: @Nick Apromollo From which version you upgraded? Can we get site url?

Comment: @nick-apromollo did you change the lifetime of the cookies? Also, did you check if an old cookie has a corresponding session in the database or files?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, This is an issue we are still experiencing, though not to an extreme degree. We can agree that the migration, while seemingly well done wasn't handled correctly. We updated from magento 1.7.2. We are able to escape this bug still, by asking the client to simply dump their cookies. Im thinking out loud here, but, I seemingly have no chance of correcting the issue without the ability to identify the old cookies and somehow write a script to remove THOSE cookies when a user visits. We aim to rebuild on 2.0.1 when available, and escape this issue completely.

Comment: Did you by any chance change the domain url? For example by adding the www prefix?